# Hard Disk failure message from windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Because of my internal hard disk failure I did a rebuild sectors by DiskPatch today. Before it, I wasn't even able to run OS. Anyway, now I can run OS, but still getting the error message. I want to know is there anything that makes me able to fix my hard disk bad sectors? I ran a scan with HD Tune and saw there is 0.7% bad blocks in my 500gb HD. I think I'm sure that all of these blocks are soft bad sectors and, by paying attention that my hard disk is healthy by most of its parts like 99.3%, What should I do? Should I replace it?

Answer (score 2):

Hard disks tend to approach failure at an exponentially increasing rate, so once you have more than a few bad blocks, and see more occuring, your time is growing very short. if the number keeps growing, replace the disk while you still can.

also check your SMART stats on the drive to see if there are any other issues. I use Speedfan to check SMART in windows, but there are other apps to do it as well.

Comment: I just can't understand this failure because I got this disk about four years ago and I don't know is it something normal to happen or not, but thanks for advice, I try to replace it.

Comment: This is just a matter of time, when your hdd will stop working at all. So if you have any info that you dont want to lose, better back it up now, and buy new hdd

Answer (score 0):

I would cut your losses, save your data while you still can, and replace it before it completely crashes. For me if a disk has bad sectors I go ahead and replace it cause as soon as the sectors start to fail you know that the drive is on its last leg anyway and shouldnt be trusted.